# Using a bash variable as file argument

Tags: bash

In bash, is there a better way to pass a variable as file argument than process substitution and `echo -n`?

```sh
v1='...'
v2='...'
comm <(echo -n "$v1") <(echo -n "$v2")
```

The following works for one file argument, at the cost of some readability:

```sh
comm <(echo -n "$v1") - <<<"$v2"
```

Maybe it is a little bit faster? Is there a better option for 2+ files? Basically, I am looking for the opposite of `v1=$(<filename)`.

Comment: Apart from the same with `printf`, not really. However, it's worth checking if this data should be in variables in the first place. Storing files and large outputs in variables is a common antipattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ v1=$(seq 1 3); v2=$(seq 2 4)

$ comm /dev/fd/3 3<<<"$v1" /dev/fd/4 4<<<"$v2"
1
                2
                3
        4
```

In the above `3<<<"$v1"` and `4<<<"$v2"` is making file descriptors 3 and 4 point to the temp files generated by the `<<<`s and then running `comm` on those file descriptors. Using awk you can see that happens:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for (i in ARGV) print i, ARGV[i]} {print FILENAME, $0}' /dev/fd/3 3<<<"$v1" /dev/fd/4 4<<<"$v2" 
0 awk
1 /dev/fd/3
2 /dev/fd/4
/dev/fd/3 1
/dev/fd/3 2
/dev/fd/3 3
/dev/fd/4 2
/dev/fd/4 3
/dev/fd/4 4
```

You can change the command line order of FD assignment vs usage if you find some other arrangement more readable and you can keep going, e.g.:

```
$ v3=$(seq 4 6); v4=$(seq 6 8)

$ paste /dev/fd/3 3<<<"$v1" /dev/fd/4 4<<<"$v2" /dev/fd/5 5<<<"$v3" /dev/fd/6 6<<<"$v4"
1       2       4       6
2       3       5       7
3       4       6       8
```

but you should really question why you're doing that if you do find yourself considering it as chances are there's a better approach for whatever it is you really need to do.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148153/133219 for more info.

Comment: That's actually a clever way to do it. So it is not all that different from process substitution which is using the same FDs. I hope (and think) that this does not actually put the data on disk because that's what I wanted to avoid. Otherwise I could have used temp files anyway.

Comment: I have come across this situation a few times in the past wondering if there was a better way. Last time I had to do several computation steps (leading up to those variables) and then needed `awk` to work on them. It only takes files (and stdin) for input. And the `echo -n` stuff always felt like "useless of echo".

Comment: I'm afraid here strings like `<<<`, just like with `<<` for here documents, use a temporary file. There's no way to do what you want without one AFAIK since your command is expecting to read from **files**.

Comment: Looks like even for a here string, bash uses a temporary file instead of piping stdin. I was under the assumption this would be more efficient because it would not hit the disk. In the end, `echo -n abc | somecommand` might be even more efficient than `somecommand <<<'abc'`.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand, but it looks like you're overthinking it.

```
awk '{print $2}' "$v1" "$v2"
```

If {v1} and {v2} are not filenames, but data, you can use a heredoc:

```
awk '{print $2}' <<EOF
$v1
$v2
EOF
```

Or a here-string:

```
awk '{print $2}' RS=: <<< "$v1:$v2"
```

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are strings, not filenames. Solution 2 and 3 assume that both could just be concatenated. This question is about cases when this is not possible, e.g. if the `awk` script would use the `NR==FNR` trick to do something different for the first file. Also, `awk` is just an example. It could also be `comm` which expects two file arguments.

Comment: Why would you use file slurp `$(<file)` in the first place, if what you want is to process files? Are you using some other utility that you only know how to use on strings? You've abstracted this problem.

Comment: As I wrote `v1=$(<filename)` is not what I am looking for but roughly the opposite. It has different use cases of course.